# lazyMap is actually not lazy?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

Here is an example from the stairway book:

```
object Example1 {
  def lazyMap[T, U](coll: Iterable[T], f: T => U) = {
    new Iterable[U] {
      def iterator = coll.iterator.map(f)
    }
  }
  val v = lazyMap[Int, Int](Vector(1, 2, 3, 4), x => {
    println("Run!")
    x * 2
  })
}
```

Result in console:

```
Run!
Run!
Run!
Run!
v: Iterable[Int] = (2, 4, 6, 8)
```

How is this lazy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is calling the map function is because you are running in the Scala console which calls the `toString` function on the lazyMap.  If you make sure not to return the value by adding a `""` to the end of your code it will not map:

```
scala> def lazyMap[T, U](coll: Iterable[T], f: T => U) = {
        new Iterable[U] {
          def iterator = coll.iterator.map(f)
        }
      }
lazyMap: [T, U](coll: Iterable[T], f: T => U)Iterable[U]

scala> lazyMap[Int, Int](Vector(1, 2, 3, 4), x => {
        println("Run!")
        x * 2
      }); ""
res8: String = ""

scala>
```